# What's the most reliable effect to cause screen tearing or stuttering?

Tags: opengl, doublebuffered, blit, double-buffering, vsync

I'm trying to investigate the various strategies to reduce or eliminate [screen tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing), such as the various vsync implementations, manual frame rate timing, double-buffering, etc.  I plan to create a tutorial or paper explaining my findings.

However, to begin with, I need to create a simple opengl program that demonstrates the effect so I'll know how well the various strategies work.  What types of animations and effects are most likely to produce tearing?  I know that quick movement often triggers it, but I'm assuming there's some kind of equation or rule of thumb that I can use.

I have tried googling for this, but I can only find endless threads on how to stop tearing, no methodical ways to create it.

Comment: You could just alternate between blitting black and white images to the default framebuffer each frame. Strobing black and white to the screen like that should make any partial frame about as obvious as it is ever going to get. Also make sure you do this in fullscreen, the DWM in newer versions of Windows implicitly prevents tearing - you can draw at 12,000 FPS if you want without tearing on Windows 8 in windowed mode, because it owns the front-buffer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks! I'll give that a try. I'm actually developing in linux, but the situation is similar there.  Compositing window managers prevent tearing at the cost of performance and control, and you have to go fullscreen to actually see it.